# asp.net-mvc 3 c# Math.round not rounding floats like 0.010000001 or 0.2399999999997

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, rounding

I have the following code in my controller:

```
    private void setProgress(float value)
    {
        progress = (float)Math.Round(value,4);
    }
```

But when value is something like the numbers in the title (a number very close to an int) it doesn't work and progress just gets the original value.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Research basic floating point information.

Comment: Part of that problem is with the way `float` and `decimal` represent numbers.  It doesn't mean it didn't round it, per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because 1 and 24 may not represented exactly using binary floating-point numbers, depending on how those numbers were calculated.  If you need a true integer, round it then convert it to an int:

```
private void setProgress(float value)
{
    progress = Convert.ToInt32((float)Math.Round(value,0));
}
```

if you need to *compare* a float to an int (even a constant one, then compare the *difference* to some very small number:

```
private bool AreCloseEnoughToEqual(double d1, double d2)
{
    const double _EPSILON = 0.00000001;
    return Math.Abs(d1-d2) < _EPSILON;
}
```

If you need to *display* it as if it were an integer, display it with 0 decimal places:

```
 Console.WriteLine("{0:N0}",d1);
```

Comment: The problem is that i need a float, but in case of an int value just need 1.00 or 24.00

Comment: @DStanley: Are you sure about that?  I think values without any decimal portion can be represented in a float.  At least 1 and 24 both can be.

Comment: Actually I messed up and said 23.9999995 where I should have said 0.23999995. I'm doing progress * 100 to display it on screen later.

Comment: @Mornaner - It if's just a display issue I would just display enough digits to be close enough (e.g. show 2 decimals to get 24.00).  If you need to compare (e.g. to see if a number is equal to 24) then use the method in my answer.